# How can I sort an associative object by value in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, object

What is the best way for sorting an "associative" object in Python by value?

I have an object with associative key and float value:

```
data = {
    u'195': 1.33,
    u'716': 0.99,
    u'562': 0.53,
    u'310': 0.5900000000000001,
    u'88' : 0.7,
    u'426': 0.88
}
```

And I need:

```
data = {
    u'195': 1.33,
    u'716': 0.99,
    u'426': 0.88,
    u'88':  0.7,
    u'310': 0.5900000000000001,
    u'562': 0.53
}
```

Comment: It's not "associateive" object, it's dictionary. And it's unordered by "design". What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I have this dictionary from a json string (data=json.loads(string)) and i need sorting by value, how i can do it?

Comment: there is no order in dictionary. you can try using list of tuples